# My Start button turned into a plain gray text "Start" button. How can I fix this?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I don't know how it happened, but my Start button has turned to plain text instead of the Windows logo. I don't even know how to Google this problem:

[image]

Anyone know what could cause this and how I can get it to go away? I never thought I'd miss a Windows logo... but that's *ugly*.

Update: sfc /scannow comes back clean. Resetting to Start Menu defaults did nothing. Value of `Shell` key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` is `explorer.exe`. New user profile started up without this button, so it must be specific to my profile.

Comment: What is in `Shell` value of key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`?

Comment: @Maximus explorer.exe

Comment: May be explorer.exe is modified? try to 'Run as Administrator' `sfc.exe /scannow`?

Comment: Similar question http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistaannouncements/thread/e729f8e2-a974-4026-8cf2-38ae6f63e7b1

Comment: Rebuilding icon cache worked. Thanks for getting rid of that ugly sucker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a similar question on [social.technet.microsoft.com](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistaannouncements/thread/e729f8e2-a974-4026-8cf2-38ae6f63e7b1).

The solution was [rebuilding icon cache](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/117229-icon-cache-rebuild.html):

1. Delete the file `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\IconCache.db`.
2. Reboot.